# SignalR HubConnection Invalid URI

Tags: c#, signalr, owin

Based on an example I found, http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Sep/04/SelfHosting-SignalR-in-a-Windows-Service, I'm implementing a SignalR host server within a Windows Service.

It all works fine but if I try:

```
SignalR = WebApp.Start<SignalRStartup>("http://*:8080/");
```

I get an unhandled exception of type `

```
'System.UriFormatException'` occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
```

It works fine if I use

```
SignalR = WebApp.Start<SignalRStartup>("http://localhost:8080/");
```

Probably a dumb assumption but based on the article I took this from, I assumed the *:8080 syntax would work.  My question is, have I missed something or was the article incorrect and this format won't work?

Comment: It seems like that should work, see [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx); does it reject "http://+:8080/" as well? Could this be caused somewhere else? What's the version of the self-host libs you're using?

Comment: And yes, both * and + get rejected. As does just leaving out the hostname entirely.  The problem is if you try to access the Owin hosted service from a remote box, or even on the same box but by the machine name or IP address, it does not connect and you get an `HTTP 400 The request hostname is invalid.`

Answer (score 1):

So, the + does work... (and yes, I feel dumb) During my testing I think only 1/2 the time I remembered to run as administrator, which lead to bad test results since it was failing because of trying to open the port, and not because of the address.

I got clued into this by reading the Owin/Katana source code linked by @DigitalD.  Turns out that not only does it support the + syntax, there is a comment from the code saying it's assuming it...

http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener/OwinHttpListener.cs

```
// Assume http(s)://+:9090/BasePath/, including the first path slash. May be empty. Must end with a slash.
```

Comment: if you don't want to run as admin, you can do this: `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8081/ user=DOMAIN\user` (replacing the relevant parts with your data), see [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the port number from the URI?

try

`http://localhost` instead of `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: Thanks for the post, but I already posted the cause, and solution, as an answer to my own question.